# How do I create the category pages?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I'm doing something similar. I have a recipe blog and I will have different categories such as breakfast, dessert, lunch, etc... But I don't know how to link them the category pages. For example, If the users click "see all" for the breakfast category, it will show all breakfast post from the breakfast category. So that means it will link to the main breakfast category page. For each category i will show 10 recent post so the users is not seeing all post. So they have the option to see all the post if they click the "see all" link. It will link them to the main category page with all breakfast post. Of course if they click the dessert "see all" link, it will link them to the dessert category page which they can see all dessert posts.

This is my current code: 
(but what php code should i put for the "see all" link? IF you take a look at my "see all" a tag, it's # right now. It's not linking to somewhere, but how do i make it dynamic to link to the categories pages. So for example if i'm in the dessert section, if i click "see all" it will link to the dessert category. )

Please also take a look at my design
[image: My Recipe page]

```html
<?php 

get_header();

?> 

<!-- recipe -->
<section class="recipe-wrap">

 <?php
 /*
  * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
  */
 $post_type = 'recipe';
 $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
  
 // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
 $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
  
 foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
  
     // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
     $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
  
     foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

 <div class="recipe-category owl-carousel-slide">
  <div class="row">

   <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?><a href="#">see all</a></h2>
         
         <div class="recipe-category-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">

          <?php
          $args = array(
                  'post_type' => $post_type,
                  'posts_per_page' => 10,  //show all posts
                  'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                          'field' => 'slug',
                          'terms' => $term->slug,
                      )
                  )
   
              );
          $posts = new WP_Query($args);
   
          if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

             <div class="item recipe-box">

              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo(types_render_field('artwork', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">
                  <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                 </a>
             </div> 

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
           </div>
          
           </section>
    
       <?php endforeach;
    
   endforeach; ?>

         </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /recipe -->

<?php 

get_footer();

?>
```

Please see the example that I provided, so you know what i'm talking about.
I have attach some images and link.

[image: Code Category]
[image: Design Category]

This is the example of the links.

This is the blog link

https://iamsteve.me/blog

[Design Category link](https://iamsteve.me/blog/category/design)

https://iamsteve.me/blog/category/design

[An example what I want](https://iamsteve.me/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to link to each category page, you can use [get_term_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) like so:

```
$category_page_link = get_term_link($term);

<h2><?php echo $term->name; ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_page_link ); ?>">see all</a></h2>
```

The above goes **inside** the second foreach loop.

**EDIT:**

This is the full code, I put the function `get_term_link()` where it should be. Also you had some problems with opening/closing html tags:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
/*
 * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
 */
$post_type = 'recipe';
$category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
?>
<section class="recipe-wrap">

<?php foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
        $term_page_link = get_term_link($term); ?>

        <div class="recipe-category owl-carousel-slide">
            <div class="row">
                <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url ( $term_page_link ); ?>">see all</a></h2>
                <div class="recipe-category-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <?php
                    $args  = array(
                        'post_type'      => $post_type,
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,  //show all posts
                        'tax_query'      => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => $term->slug,
                            )
                        )

                    );
                    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ( $posts->have_posts() ):
                        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="item recipe-box">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo( types_render_field( 'artwork', array( 'raw' => true ) ) ); ?>">
                                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- .owl-theme -->
            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- owl-carousel-slide -->

    <?php endforeach; // terms loop ?>

<?php endforeach; // taxonomies loop ?>

</section><!-- /recipe -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work. Where should I add this $category_page_link = get_term_link($term);?

Comment: Put it inside the second foreach loop, bellow `foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>`. If it still doesn't work, write `var_dump($category_page_link)` bellow `$category_page_link = get_term_link($term);` and copy the results.

Comment: I try and it doesn't work. I want to  send you the screenshot but how do i send it here?

Comment: I got this code "$category_page_link = get_term_link($term); var_dump($category_page_link);" when i preview my site. Do you know why?

Comment: Make sure you put this code insinde php tags: `<?php $category_page_link = get_term_link($term); var_dump($category_page_link); ?>`

Comment: Omg it works perfect :) Thanks for your help ... but i have another question about category page. How do I display all my breakfast post in my breakfast  category? and the same for dessert post in my dessert category? like what is the which loop ? So the dynamic code for the individual category pages, for example https://iamsteve.me/blog/category/design . This shows all design post in the design category. Appreciated .

Comment: If I answer your question, please accept my answer and give an up-vote. About your question, it depends on your theme, usually in order to change the template of the category page you need to modify the file `category.php`.